# Leave money and return the same amount

Tags: money, muslim-practices

I hope you have a good day.

I recently discovered riba (Gaining money through interest, among others etc ...), but I have two doubts.

1.- A few months ago a friend of mine wanted me to help him in exchange for a payment of € 400, to make the documentation (word presentation to show the client (investor) how the apartment is, among other things), after a few days, I do not know if it was before or after the deal of giving me more money, he sold it and told me that instead of € 400 I will pay you € 1200. But with the situation of COVID his payment has been delayed and he has not yet received it I think it was for bureaucratic issues and now he works in a restaurant and he wants to pay me monthly (Paying me every month a fixed quantity until the reach of the final price 1200€) I had told him that he didn't have to pay I have no problem doing it for free but he wants me to pay. In this case can the money be accepted or not? (I had read that money earned from people’s difficulty or something was not acceptable either from riba and just in case he's not muslim i doubt there's any difference if he was or not but just in case i'll write it).

2.- A friend wants money to be able to go to a place (job interview) and asks me to leave (giving money to him then later on he will return to me the same quantity of money) him money (20 €) and he would return it to me, he also asked me to leave money to pay for a room (75 €) and I gave the money, in these two cases I told him to return the same amount later and I do not know if it is valid to accept this money or not (The friend is the first case and now he is working in that restaurant).

The final question is: Is it okay to accept this money for personal use of the two previous cases ? I also ask this because it makes me feel bad as  if i'm accepting something that's not good not legal.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is actually lending and not usury. You borrowed money and reminded your friend that he should repay the loan.
Usury means increase, growth, profit and more than the principle of taking property. That means you lend money, but tell him he has to pay your interest every month until he repays the loan. That one person lends money to another as long as the debtor pays a larger amount, which in jurisprudence is called Borrow usury.
One of the things that Islam has emphasized a lot is the issue of lending to the needy, to the extent that in our narrations it is considered superior to charity. For Qarz al-Hasna, this favorable tradition, the conditions stated in the longest verse of the Qur'an.
Even one of the things that is recommended in lending to the parties is that the lending be written down and it should be clear how much the lender has lent for how long. Unfortunately, most people do not comply with the terms of the lending. And sometimes they get hurt.

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa15312

https://hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/12280/%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7-%DA%86%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%88-%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%AD%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%84-%DA%A9%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA

Comment: The first link gives me an "Error", the second is in Arabic only. As far as I know, many Muslims around the world can't read or even speak Arabic.